# How can I detect a Scrollbar presence ( using Javascript ) in HTML iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, scrollbar

How can I detect a Scrollbar presence ( using Javascript ) in HTML iFrame ?

**I have already tried :**

```
        var vHeight = 0;
        if (document.all) {
          if (document.documentElement) {
            vHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
          } else {
            vHeight = document.body.clientHeight
          }
    } else {
      vHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }

    if (document.body.offsetHeight > vHeight) {
      //when theres a scrollbar
    }else{
      //when theres not a scrollbar
    }
```

**And I also had tried :**

```
           this.scrollLeft=1;
    if (this.scrollLeft>0) {
        //when theres a scrollbar
        this.scrollLeft=0;
        }else{
        //when theres not a scrollbar
        return false;
    }
```

With no success..

I have searched  the *javascript objets* on *DOM Inspector*, but didn't find anything.

Is is possible to detect a scrollbar presence in a iframe in javacscript ?

---

The iframe content comes from the same domain.

No success until now..

[alt text http://www.upvtp.com.br/file.php/1/help_key.jpg](http://www.upvtp.com.br/file.php/1/help_key.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jQuery you can compare the document height, the scrollTop position and the viewport height, which might get you the answer you require.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(isMyStuffScrolling()){
    //There is a scroll bar here!
  }
}); 

function isMyStuffScrolling() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var scroll    = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
  return (docHeight == scroll);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your code only tests when I try to move the scrollbar. I want a to test it on page load.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a correct solution. :( Your code actually checks, whether document is scrolled to the bottom. Here is a proof: http://jsfiddle.net/vvdb0292/2/. I think bobince's answer is correct.

Answer (score 48):

```
var root= document.compatMode=='BackCompat'? document.body : document.documentElement;
var isVerticalScrollbar= root.scrollHeight>root.clientHeight;
var isHorizontalScrollbar= root.scrollWidth>root.clientWidth;
```

This detects whether there is a *need* for a scrollbar. For the default of iframes this is the same as whether there *is* a scrollbar, but if scrollbars are forced on or off (using the ‘scrolling="yes"/"no"’ attribute in the parent document, or CSS ‘overflow: scroll/hidden’ in the iframe document) then this may differ.

Comment: Why do you test for 'BackCompat' instead of just using the `documentElement` in all compat modes?

Comment: @bab when you're in Quirks Mode (IE5 compat) the top-level document scrollbar is on the body element instead of html.

Comment: For further simplicity you could replace the `compatMode` check with `var root = document.scrollingElement;`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(isMyStuffScrolling()){
//scrolling
  }else{
//not scrolling
}
}); 

function isMyStuffScrolling() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var scroll    = $(window).height() ;//+ $(window).scrollTop();
  if(docHeight > scroll) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

improved-changed a bit from Jon`s Winstanley code

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this can be done if the iframe content comes from another domain due to JavaScript security limitations.

EDIT:
In that case, something along the lines of giving the iframe a name='someframe' and id='someframe2' and then comparing frames['someframe'].document.body.offsetWidth with document.getElementById('someframe2').offsetWidth should give you the answer.

Comment: The iframe content comes from the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this works on any element, at least on Chrome:

```
hasVerticalScrollbar = (element.scrollHeight > element.offsetHeight)
        || 
(element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight
```

Horizontal scrollbars can be detected the same, using `Width` instead of `Height`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second attempt is on the right track. Except instead of `this`, you should try scrolling/checking `document.body`.