# how to feature detect hidden scroll bars?

Tags: css

is there a way to feature detect hidden scroll bars? is there a library that already does this? specifically, these are touch devices or computers that hide scrollbars like OS X with a touchpad.

Comment: Does this help? [How can I detect a Scrollbar presence ( using Javascript ) in HTML iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/681087)

Comment: no, because i'm not checking an iframe, and the current page doesn't necessarily have overflow to warrant a scrollbar already

Comment: The answer isn't just applicable to `iframe`'s. Did you see bobince's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modernizr added this! https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1029 you'll have to use master though as 3.0 hasn't been released