# How to detect the presence of a scrollbar in the Dom using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to detect presence of scrollbar in the Dom measuring body height and window height in JavaScript? I want the syntax.

Comment: you might be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681087/how-can-i-detect-a-scrollbar-presence-using-javascript-in-html-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an element has scrollbar using scrollHeight property of the element

```
if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight)
```

PS: if you don't know the overflow property of the element, you might wanna add additional check for overflow

```
if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight && element.style.overflowY !== 'hidden') || element.style.overflowY === 'scroll')
```